# Why spring-boot with Kafka failed to start?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka

There is spring-boot application with kafka dependecy,
there are two Kafka topics and need to read messages from them

```
tacocloud.orders.topic
tacocloud.tacos.topic
```

And already successful sent messages in it

Configured kafka config for listen this topics like this

```
 package com.example.tacocloud.config;

import com.example.tacocloud.model.jpa.Order;
import com.example.tacocloud.model.jpa.Taco;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.EnableKafka;
import org.springframework.kafka.config.ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.ProducerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.listener.ContainerProperties;
import org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer;
import org.springframework.kafka.listener.MessageListener;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@Slf4j
@Configuration
@EnableKafka
@EnableConfigurationProperties
public class KafkaConfig {

  // Order

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.kafka.consumer.order")
    public Map<String, Object> orderConsumerConfig() {
        return new HashMap<>();
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<Object, Order> orderConsumerFactory(@Qualifier("orderConsumerConfig")
        Map<String, Object> orderConsumerConfig) {
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(orderConsumerConfig);
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Order> order1KafkaMessageListenerContainer(
        @Qualifier("orderConsumerConfig") Map<String, Object> orderConsumerConfig,
        @Qualifier("orderConsumerFactory") DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory orderConsumerFactory) {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(orderConsumerFactory);
        return factory;
    }

    // Taco

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.kafka.consumer.taco")
    public Map<String, Object> tacoConsumerConfig() {
        return new HashMap<>();
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory tacoConsumerFactory(
        @Qualifier("tacoConsumerConfig") Map<String, Object> tacoConsumerConfig) {
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(tacoConsumerConfig);
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory tacoConcurrentMessageListenerContainer(
        @Qualifier("tacoConsumerConfig") Map<String, Object> tacoConsumerConfig,
        @Qualifier("tacoConsumerFactory") DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory tacoConsumerFactory) {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(tacoConsumerFactory);
        return factory;
    }
}
```

So, there are two DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory and two ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory
Aften that, created a service with @KafkaListener log messages:

```
package com.example.tacocloud.service;

import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.EnableKafka;
import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaListener;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
@EnableKafka
public class KafkaService {

    @KafkaListener(topics = "tacocloud.orders.topic", groupId = "one")
    public void order() {
        System.out.println("Order");
    }

    @KafkaListener(topics ="tacocloud.tacos.topic", groupId = "two")
    public void taco() {
        System.out.println("Taco");
    }
}
```

application.yml file

```
spring:
  kafka:
    consumer:
      order:
        topic: tacocloud.orders.topic
        "[bootstrap.servers]": localhost:29888
        "[key.deserializer]": org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
        "[value.deserializer]": com.example.tacocloud.model.serialization.OrderDeserializer
        template:
          "[default.topic]": tacocloud.orders.topic
      taco:
        topic: tacocloud.tacos.topic
        "[bootstrap.servers]": localhost:29888
        "[key.deserializer]": org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
        "[value.deserializer]": com.example.tacocloud.model.serialization.TacoDeserializer
        template:
          "[default.topic]": tacocloud.tacos.topic
```

But, when I start my spring-boot application, I see error message(((

> 2022-04-15 21:38:35.918 ERROR 13888 --- [  restartedMain]
> o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
>
> org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to
> start bean
> 'org.springframework.kafka.config.internalKafkaListenerEndpointRegistry';
> nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException:
> Missing required configuration "key.deserializer" which has no default
> value.    at
> org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:181)
> ~[spring-context-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]   at
> org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:54)
> ~[spring-context-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]   at
> org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:356)
> ~[spring-context-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]   at
> java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) ~[na:na]   at
> org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:155)
> ~[spring-context-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]   at
> org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:123)
> ~[spring-context-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]   at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:935)
> ~[spring-context-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]   at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:586)
> ~[spring-context-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]   at
> org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145)
> ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]    at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:740)
> ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]    at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:415)
> ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]    at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
> ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]    at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1312)
> ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]    at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301)
> ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]    at
> com.example.tacocloud.TacoCloudApplication.main(TacoCloudApplication.java:10)
> ~[classes/:na]    at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method) ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
> at
> org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
> ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4] Caused by:
> org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Missing required
> configuration "key.deserializer" which has no default value.  at
> org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.parseValue(ConfigDef.java:493)
> ~[kafka-clients-2.8.0.jar:na]     at
> org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.parse(ConfigDef.java:483)
> ~[kafka-clients-2.8.0.jar:na]     at
> org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.(AbstractConfig.java:108)
> ~[kafka-clients-2.8.0.jar:na]     at
> org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.(AbstractConfig.java:129)
> ~[kafka-clients-2.8.0.jar:na]     at
> org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig.(ConsumerConfig.java:640)
> ~[kafka-clients-2.8.0.jar:na]     at
> org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.(KafkaConsumer.java:665)
> ~[kafka-clients-2.8.0.jar:na]     at
> org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.createRawConsumer(DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.java:416)
> ~[spring-kafka-2.8.3.jar:2.8.3]   at
> org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.createKafkaConsumer(DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.java:384)
> ~[spring-kafka-2.8.3.jar:2.8.3]   at
> org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.createConsumerWithAdjustedProperties(DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.java:360)
> ~[spring-kafka-2.8.3.jar:2.8.3]   at
> org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.createKafkaConsumer(DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.java:327)
> ~[spring-kafka-2.8.3.jar:2.8.3]   at
> org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.createConsumer(DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.java:304)
> ~[spring-kafka-2.8.3.jar:2.8.3]   at
> org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:758)
> ~[spring-kafka-2.8.3.jar:2.8.3]   at
> org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer.doStart(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:344)
> ~[spring-kafka-2.8.3.jar:2.8.3]   at
> org.springframework.kafka.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.start(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:442)
> ~[spring-kafka-2.8.3.jar:2.8.3]   at
> org.springframework.kafka.listener.ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer.doStart(ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer.java:209)
> ~[spring-kafka-2.8.3.jar:2.8.3]   at
> org.springframework.kafka.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.start(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:442)
> ~[spring-kafka-2.8.3.jar:2.8.3]   at
> org.springframework.kafka.config.KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.startIfNecessary(KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.java:331)
> ~[spring-kafka-2.8.3.jar:2.8.3]   at
> org.springframework.kafka.config.KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.start(KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.java:276)
> ~[spring-kafka-2.8.3.jar:2.8.3]   at
> org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:178)
> ~[spring-context-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]   ... 19 common frames omitted
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: ` Missing required configuration "key.deserializer" which has no default value` - does it say anything to you? WE just don't know what are your `spring.kafka.consumer.order`. So, it might not be a surprise that there are no some required props provided.

Comment: @ArtemBilan added application.yml

Comment: I'm not so good with YAML to be sure in that `"[key.deserializer]"` syntax. Also I've never seen that `@ConfigurationProperties` on a `Map` bean. Any chances to share with us a simple project to let us reproduce and play with.

Comment: @ArtemBilan placed it on github
https://github.com/VOsipenkov/Kafka-issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for a sample.

So, I opened it locally and placed a break point into this bean definition:

```
@Bean
public DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<Object, Order> orderConsumerFactory(@Qualifier("orderConsumerConfig")
    Map<String, Object> orderConsumerConfig) {
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<Object, Order>(orderConsumerConfig);
}
```

That `orderConsumerConfig` map looks like this:

```
orderConsumerConfig = {LinkedHashMap@8587}  size = 1
 "orderConsumerConfig" -> {HashMap@8600}  size = 5
  key = "orderConsumerConfig"
  value = {HashMap@8600}  size = 5
   "key.deserializer" -> "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer"
   "template" -> {LinkedHashMap@8611}  size = 1
   "topic" -> "tacocloud.orders.topic"
   "bootstrap.servers" -> "localhost:29888"
   "value.deserializer" -> "sample.kafka.serializer.OrderDeserializer"
```

so, that's indeed not a surprise that your `KafkaConsumer` is not initialized properly. Your target map config is hidden under that `orderConsumerConfig` entry of this injected map.

Would you mind to share with me from where did you take an idea of the `@ConfigurationProperties` on the `Map` bean? And how that supposed to be used as dependency injection?

Comment: Thank you very much. It was inccorect from my side to use Map in configuration

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to do something similar (configure multiple `ConsumerFactories`) based on properties.
I used `@ConfigurationProperties` to create a `Map<String,String>` instead of `Map<String,Object>` and then added the items of that map into a new `Map<String,Object>`. Not sure why Spring-Boot loaded the `Map<String,Object>` that way.

```
@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties("taco-cart.kafka")
public Map<String, String> tacoCartKafkaProperties() {
    return new HashMap<>();
}

@Bean
public ConsumerFactory<String, TacoCart> tacoCartConsumerFactory(@Qualifier("tacoCartKafkaProperties") Map<String, String> tacoCartKafkaProperties) {

    // Convert map.
    Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<>();
    config.putAll(tacoCartKafkaProperties);

    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(config);
}
```